# factor by the leading term to compute a limit depending on $\pm \infty$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I have to compute the limit of $ f(x)=\frac{2+x+e^x}{2+x-e^x}$ when $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$.
My question is about the leading term. Am I right if I consider that $e^x$ is my leading term when $x \to +\infty$ and then I could factor by this term to remove the IF  like this ?
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)= \lim_{x\to +\infty}=\frac{e^x(\frac{2}{e^x}+\frac{x}{e^x}+1)}{e^x(\frac{2}{e^x}+\frac{x}{e^x}-1)} =-1$$

On the other hand, what about when $x\to -\infty$ ?  Am I right if I consider in this case that $x$ is my leading term when $x \to -\infty$ ?

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)= \lim_{x\to -\infty}=\frac{x(\frac{2}{x}+1+\frac{e^x}{x})}{x(\frac{2}{x}+1-\frac{e^x}{x})} = 1$$

EDIT :
Is there another method to calculate the limit of this function when $x \to - \infty$ ?

Comment: yes both works.

Comment: Is there another method to calculate the limit of this function when → -∞ ?

Comment: you could use L'hopital rule...

Comment: This is no urge for another method, in fact factoring out the dominant term is the basis for equivalents you'll learn later : In $+\infty$ then $f(x)\sim\dfrac{e^x}{-e^x}\to -1$ and in $-\infty$ then $f(x)\sim\dfrac xx\to 1$. So it is good to get familiarized to it. On the other hand, l'Hospital rule will also be substituted later for Taylor expansions which goes along with equivalents.

Comment: But why in this case $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}$ are equal for $\frac{x^2+2x-1}{x^2-2x+1}$ ? In fact, we have $x^2$ as lead term when $x \to +\infty$ and $2x$ as lead term when $x\to -\infty$ ?

Comment: No, you still have $x^2$ dominant for both. In $-\infty$ you have $|x^2|\gg |2x|$ because $|x^2/2x|=|x/2|\to\infty$. Here the difference is $e^x\to 0$ at $-\infty$.

Comment: Concerning terminology: "dominant term" is correct for this. "Leading term" has a different meaning.